# How to monitor request queue time in Play?

Tags: performance, playframework, threadpool, monitoring

I have this play `Job` running, but the active thread count are low compared to how many requests I'm actually hitting it with. I know it's run every second which can miss some information, but it's consistently lower even with high volume of requests.

```
@Every("1s")
public class FooJob extends Job<Void> {
    @Override
    public void doJob() {
        storeMetric("activethreads", Invoker.executor.getActiveCount());
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: 1.4 land I can't upgrade